# Got HTTP Error 404.17 while setting up asp.net project onto IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, webserver, iis-8

I am trying to set up an existing asp.net application onto IIS 8.0 on my windows 8 machine and it giving me the following error message.

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

I googled for a while and trying to solve this problem with several solutions such as registering asp.net manually. However,it is still not working.
Most of the solutions are for IIS 7.5 and the problem is the same or not.

Any idea!
really appreciate.

Comment: Have you checked that the correct version of .NET is selected for the App Pool?

Answer (score 8):

As the blogger that Gearhart refers to points out, the problem may be that .NET 3.5 is not installed for IIS.  3.5 handles the down-level apps including 2.0.

The procedure in the blog looks simple and may work fine.  However the "official" procedure from Microsoft looks different:

Step 1: Install IIS and ASP.NET Modules
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831475.aspx

Scroll down to the section on Windows 8.  (I'm using Server 2012 and the procedure for that worked for me.)

Comment: Thanks Mark - the section "To install IIS and ASP.NET modules by using the command line" in your link worked for me on Win 8.1 Update 1 / IIS 8.5.

Comment: Had the same issue, installing .NET 3.5 fixed it!  Thanks!  My application pool is using .NET CLR v2.  This is on MS Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem se blow link for solution

http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/110/-Net-wont-run-HTTP-Error-404-17-Not-Found.aspx

Comment: .NET 3.5 was already installed on my machine but somehow 2.0 was not installed/configured. Following the instructions on the linked page helped me with my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on Server 2012 R2. For me the fix documented [here](http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/110/-Net-wont-run-HTTP-Error-404-17-Not-Found.aspx) worked.

In essence...

The fix is simple:

- Launch Command Prompt - Start - cmd.exe
- cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
- aspnet_regiis -ir

You should see output like:

```
Start installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
................
Finished installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
```

At this point if you refresh your page it should work properly. HTH

Answer (score -2):

Thanks it work.

I had the same error...and  i run command prompt

HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
Most likely causes:

```
The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.
```

Things you can try:

```
If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.
```

Detailed Error Information:
Module     StaticFileModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070032
Requested URL      http://localhost:8080/WebForms/index.aspx
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HRMS\WebForms\index.aspx
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

Comment: This post merely documents the symptoms of the problem, and does not describe an actual answer.  To support someone else's answer, it would be more useful to upvote their answer and possibly leave a comment on their answer.